# getJSON running order

Tags: jquery, getjson

I'm fully aware that getJSON runs asynchronously however I'm having trouble understanding why my program is always returning the same data. I'm looping through a list of possible sites to query and using getJSON to return data then manipulating the data however on each iteration of my loop the data that I'm getting back seems to be the same. When running this code directly I get the expected value (not in a loop). There have been odd occasions when I've received the second or third set of data however I'm assuming that this is caused by the network being faster than usual.

```
var songObj;

for(i = 0; i < networks.length; i++)
{
    runJSON(networks[i],"track",false);

    songObj = [];

    $.when.apply($, deferreds).then(function() {
        songObj = ($.grep(songList, function(e){return e.artist == curSong[0].artist}));
        console.log(songList);
        imgCode  =  "<a href='" + songObj[0].link 
                 + "'><img id = 'spotifyLogo' src='images/spotify.jpg' alt='mIage'></a>";
        theValue = imgCode + "<br>"
                 + "Available on Spotify for " + songObj[0].price
                 + "<br> <br>";

        $("#songDisplay").append(theValue);
        deferreds = [], index;
    });
}

function runJSON(network,searchType,display){
    var URL  = returnURL(network,searchType,$('#song_field').val().split(' ').join("+"));

    var val  = $('#song_field').val();
    var data = {val: val}

    deferreds.push($.getJSON(URL, data, function(data){

        if(document.getElementById("box") !== "undefined" && display == true){
            clearScreen();
            createCols();
        }

        songList = [];
        eval(network + "(data);");

        if(display === true){
            for(i = 0; i < songList.length; i++)
            {   
                displayTrack(i);
            }
        }

        done = true; 

    }));
}
```

Comment: The global `songList` being set in each `runJSON` success handler concerns me (or it would, if anything were ever added to it, I assume you removed some code that does that). There's every chance that all of the `getJSON` handlers will run before any of the `then()` handlers run. All of those handlers will get the same (last) `songList` values.

Comment: @PaulRoub You're correct in that the last songList values are always being returned. The code that adds to songList is in displayTracks () which I didn't copy in because I wasn't sure it was relevant it's essentially pushing the data I want out of the json into the object. Why would that be a concern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code says this:

1. Start a bunch of asynchronous operations
2. Wait for them all to complete (`$.when.apply(...)`)
3. Process the `songList` array

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

> In the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to jQuery.when(), the method returns the Promise from a new "master" Deferred object that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds it has been passed. The method will resolve its master Deferred as soon as **all the Deferreds resolve**

Each one of your asynchronous operations goes

1. Clear out the `songList` array
2. Add some data to the `songList` array

So therefore your flow is going to go (for example; order may vary)

- Clear out `songList`, add list 1 to `songList`
- Clear out `songList`, add list 2 to `songList`
- ...
- Clear out `songList`, add list *n* to `songList`
- Process `songList`

i.e. whichever asynchronous operation happens to execute last clears out whatever was in there before and adds just its list.

If you really want to stick to using your global `songList` variable, instead of clearing it out in each runJSON invocation, you could clear it out before the loop and then just append all the results into a long list. Or to keep them separate, have it as an array of arrays (for example).

Comment: I can't believe how simple this was, thank you soooo much! I've been banging my head against this all day and got nowhere.